# Problema com aplicação para filtro de stopwords e acentos

Tags: python

Bom dia, estou tentando desenvolver um algoritmo simples em Python para remoção de stop words de textos, porém estou tendo problemas com palavras que tenham acentos.

O Código é o seguinte:

```
import io
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from unicodedata import normalize
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('portuguese'))
file1 = open("C:\Users\Desktop\Teste.txt")
print("Arquivo lido!")
line = file1.read()
palavras = line.split()
#Converte as palavra para letra minúscula
palavras = [palavra.lower() for palavra in palavras]
print("Rodando!")
for r in palavras:
    if r not in stop_words:
            appendFile = open('textofiltrado.txt','a')
            appendFile.writelines(" "+r)
            appendFile.close()

print("Concluido!")
```

Ao rodar o código com o seguinte arquivo de teste:

```
E É Á A O Ó U Ú
```

Eu tenho essa saída:

```
 É Á Ó Ú
```

Ou seja, ele não reconhece palavras que tenham acento, usar o setdefaultencoding para utf-8 não funcionou, alguém sabe alguma solução que eu possa usar para resolver esse problema?

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
palavra.decode('utf-8').lower()
```

Fonte: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2145841/4649737)

Comment: Ao se usar essa solução ele apresenta um problema na hora de escrever no arquivo de saída (Em appendFile.writelines )

Comment: Faça `.encode('utf-8')` no final, cara. Ou então abra outra pergunta